# Failed to execute goal org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:2.5.5:run (default-cli)

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, maven

I'm new to Spring and I was trying to follow the tutorial given on its official website and this error pop up.

```
Failed to execute goal org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:2.5.5:run (default-cli) on project backend: Application finished with exit code: 1 -> [Help 1]
```

The following is my pom.xml

4.0.0

org.springframework.boot
spring-boot-starter-parent
2.5.5
 

com.example
backend
0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
backend
Demo project for Spring Boot

<java.version>11</java.version>

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.7.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.7.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <mainClass>BackendApplication</mainClass>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>repackage</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.5</version>
            <configuration>
                <skipTests>false</skipTests>
                <testFailureIgnore>true</testFailureIgnore>
                <forkMode>once</forkMode>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>           
    </plugins>
    
</build>
```

Any idea why is not working? I have try many approaches based on other people's error but none of it work. Kinda frustrated now. Any assistance would be appreciated

Comment: Run your maven with `-X` parameter to get the reason on the logs, if still not helpful, post the stack trace of the application here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error is basically due to a plugin issue.

**create a jar for the project**  by running these commands

`mvn clean install` and then `java -jar jar-localtion.jar`